# The behaviors of optimizier.apply_gradients() when using multiple optimizers

Tags: optimization, tensorflow

I want to train neural network with two losses. I define two `tf.train.Adamoptimizer()` as `optim1` and `optim2` to optimize two losses `loss1` and `loss2`.

In my network, partial layers in, say set **S**, contribute to both losses. Now if I need to train the whole network end2end using two optimizers. Can I simply do

```
gradient_1 = tf.gradients(loss_1, vars_1)
train_op_1 = optim1.apply_gradients(zip(gradient_1, vars_1))

gradient_2 = tf.gradients(loss_2, vars_2)
train_op_2 = optim1.apply_gradients(zip(gradient_2, vars_2))

sess.run([train_op_1, train_op_2])
```

Will the two gradients from two optimizers belong to **S** accumulate automatically? Or each time `apply_gradients` is applied, the gradient will be zeroed. If it is the latter, my current implementation is wrong. I may need to define a new loss `loss = loss1 + loss2` as https://github.com/jg8610/multi-task-part-1-notebook/blob/master/Multi-Task%20Learning%20Tensorflow%20Part%201.ipynb suggested. 
However, that solution is not very flexible if I want to do more operations to `gradient_1 and gradient_2` respectively.

Any good suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Well. I got a perfect answer from tensorflow forum. I decided not to delete this question. Here is the link(https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/discuss/OAyEveZzpso/wWpPP2hVEAAJ)